# How can I export an iPad app's data to a computer?

Tags: ios

I have a simple survey iPad app. The data is saved in a TSV (tab separated file). I'm looking for an easy way to export this TSV file to a computer (without emailing it, if possible, and without doing it through iTunes).

Comment: Just email it if it's absolutely neccisary

Answer (score 0):

App data on iOS is not directly accessible from a connected computer. It's not like you can mount the iPad's flash drive directly on a computer, navigate to the app's data directory, and copy the file to the computer. You have to have something with rights to access the data.

Some options are:

- email or otherwise 'share' the data from within the iPad app.
- Make the app's data accessible via iTunes
- Turn the app into an FTP client or server
- Dropbox integration (There was some problem where Apple was rejecting apps that did this, but i don't know the current state)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). It's a great little program / app that let's you access your iPad's file system from your computer. You can just drag and drop any file from your iPad to your computer.